# File "retrain.py", line 68, in <module> import tensorflow as tf ImportError: No module named tensorflow

Tags: python, django

I am a beginner in tensorflow and i have a problem
I install ubuntu 16.4, tensorflow 0.9, python 3.5

I want to train an Image Classifier with TensorFlow but i get this error please any one can help me.

```
 $ python retrain.py \
 --bottleneck_dir=tf_files/bottlenecks \
 --model_dir=tf_files/inception \
 --output_graph=tf_files/retrained_graph.pb \
 --output_labels=tf_files/retrained_labels.txt \
 --image_dir tf_files/blood_cells

 Traceback (most recent call last):   File "retrain.py", line 68, in
 <module>
     import tensorflow as tf ImportError: No module named tensorflow
```

Comment: Have you pip-installed tensorflow for Python3 or 2? Are you sure you are running the script with the same Python version for which tensorflow is installed?

Comment: Before this error i already have another error import error, no module named six and i do pip install six  and after this error i get this error Traceback (most recent call last): File "retrain.py", line 68, in import tensorflow as tf ImportError: No module named tensorflow

Comment: It's hard to say but looks like you have not installed correctly tensorflow or you are using the wrong Python installation to run your script. Again.. which python are you using or you want to use?

Comment: i use python 3.5

Comment: then do `python3 -m pip install tensorflow` to install it on your default Python3. Then run your script with `python3 retrain.py` be sure that your script is python3 compatible of course!

Comment: i do all the steps that you tell me to do it but i am getting this error

Comment: ValueError: Only call `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` with named arguments (labels=..., logits=..., ...)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried "activate tensorflow" before running those line?

Comment: it says permission denied